# How do I sort a list of Doubles in Scala?

Tags: scala

How do I sort a simple list of Doubles in Scala?

```
var dubs = List(1.3,4.5,2.3,3.2)
```

I think my question may not have accurately reflected my specific problem, since I realize now that dubs.sorted will work just fine for the above.  My problem is as follows, I have a string of doubles `"2.3 32.4 54.2 1.33"` that I'm parsing and adding to a list

```
var numsAsStrings = l.split("\\s");
var x = List(Double);
var i = 0;
for( i <- 0 until numsAsStrings.length) {
  x :+ numsAsStrings(i).toDouble;
}
```

So, I would think that I could just call `x.sorted` on the above, but that doesn't work...  I've been looking over the sortBy, sorted, and sortWith documentation and various posts, but I thought the solution should be simpler.  I think I'm missing something basic, regardless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort an array in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131925/how-do-i-sort-an-array-in-scala) Another dupe or close to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751434/simplest-way-to-sort-list-of-objects

Comment: I don't think you can honestly say you've researched this question before posting.

Comment: @LimbSoup.  You're right in a way, especially given what I originally posted.  I didn't accurately reflect my problem, though, which is my fault.  dubs.sorted works just fine on what I listed as the first example.  My problem may be equally trivial, but I can seem to find the easy solution I expected.  I'v added more detail to the original question

Comment: l.split("\\s").map{_.toDouble}.sorted

Comment: `List(Double)` should be `List[Double]()`. `List(Double)` is a list holding the companion object for `Double`.

Comment: "that doesn't work."  Don't make us guess. In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sorted` method

```
dubs.sorted  // List(1.3, 2.3, 3.2, 4.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the original question.  This has become a bit of a cluster @#$%, since I believe my problem has more to do with lists than sorting...